# JSF + Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Saludos tengo una consulta me estoy volviendo loco les doy un ejemplo.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:inputText id="numero" value="#{clase.valor}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" icon="pi pi-check" update=":form2" >
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
    <p:dataTable widgetVar="miwed" var="empl" id="newdata" value="#{clase.traerDatos(clase.valor)}">
        <p:column headerText="elDato">
            <h:inputText value="#{miwed.valor}" valueChangeListener="#{clase.guardar}">
            </h:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

el problema es cuando ingreso un valor en el form1 y apreto el comandbutton me trae los datos perfectos en el form2, pero ya no puedo usar ajax en el form2 quiero volver a guardar datos o actualizar y no me deja probe p:ajax f:ajax valueChangeListener nada funciona, ahora si en el form2 en clase.traerDatos(1) le pongo un valor por defecto si me trae los datos y funciona todo, solo no funciona cuando cargo el bean clase.valor en el form1.

que estoy haciendo mal?
lo que quiero hacer seria
input ingresar un numero
submit
datatable traerdatos con el numeroingresado
dentro del datatable en un input actualizar dato via ajax

Comment: Hace mucho que no trabajo con JSF pero creo que debes agregar el form1 al update del botón que tienes en ese mismo form1: update=":form1,:form2".

Comment: tambien probe con eso no hay caso.

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que nos compartas el código de tu BackingBean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trabaja todo dentro de un solo form, el contenido del primer form ponlo dentro de un h:panelGroup con un id="form1" y el contenido del form2 ponlo dentro de otro  h:panelGroup con un id="form2", y cuando tu presiones en el botón del formulario1

```
<p:commandButton value="SubmitForm1" icon="pi pi-check" process="@form:form1" update="@form:form2" >
```

se debe renderizar el contenido del segundo y en luego puedes usar ajax en el cuadro de texto para que ejecute el listener al precionar la tecla en el inputtext,

```
<h:inputText id="valorForm2" value="#{miwed.valor}" >
         <f:ajax execute="valorForm2" render="form" event="change" 
                      listener="#{clase.guardar}"/> 
   </h:inputText>
```

quedando algo como lo siguiente:

```
<h:form id="contenedor"> 
    <h:panelGroup id="form1">
            <p:inputText id="numero" value="#{clase.valor}" />
            <p:commandButton value="SubmitForm1" icon="pi pi-check" process="@form:form1" update="@form:form2" >
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="form2">
            <p:dataTable widgetVar="miwed" var="empl" id="newdata" value="#{clase.traerDatos(clase.valor)}">
                <p:column headerText="elDato">
                <h:inputText value="#{miwed.valor}" valueChangeListener="#{clase.guardar}">
                </h:inputText>
                <h:inputText id="valorForm2" value="#{miwed.valor}" >
                    <f:ajax execute="valorForm2" render="contenedor" event="change" listener="#{clase.guardar}"/> 
                </h:inputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: El problema es que todo depende del scope que esté usando en su backing bean, por eso le pedí que agregara este código.